# Update function because variable value changed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, initialization

is it necessary to update a function on a changed variable? I don't know how to explain this correctly but i'll try my best in the following.

I have a .click() function which gets initialized if the document is ready. Inside of this function is a .animate() function which uses a variable (var content) as selector. This variable is also defined if the document is ready. (Below you see a simplyfied version of the code)

```
$('.selector').click(function () {
   $(content).animate({
       scrollTop: target.offset().top
   }, 1000);
   return false;
});
```

But this variable changes between two values according to the viewport width. (Below you see a simplyfied version of the code)

```
if(viewportWidth < 768){
    content = $('.content-wrap');
}else{
    content = $('html, body');
}
```

So if the variable value is changing, do I have to update or reinitialize my function?
Because it'not working for one of the selectors.

Thanks for any help or any food for thought. :)

=============UPDATE=============

Okey, it's still not working like expected.

```
$(content).scroll(function() {
    console.log($(this));
}
```

This doesn't work if the value of the variable (content) changed. It's only working for the value which is set for this variable if the document is ready.

Comment: But what if user manually resizes window? Better to check width inside click event handler for that case

Comment: You need to update the variable on window resize.   Or better, simply call the function that updates the variable within the button click handler just before the animate.

Comment: @charlietfl yes I know. The code above is simplified. There is a resize function which changes the variable.

Comment: @freedomn-m see comment above.

Comment: The code in the update won't work when you resize as it will have assigned the `scroll` event handler to the element pointed to by `content` *at the time you assign the event handler*.   This is a very different issue from the original question.

Comment: In the case of the update, assign the scroll handler to *both* (/ all) possible combinations then check which currently matches content - something like `if ($(this) == content) console.log($(this))`

Comment: @freedomn-m I think the issue is not very different because the second problem describes my thoughts behind this.
Anyways, you gave me the tip. I'll check inside the scroll event, which value for the content is set. :) Thanks

Comment: You see them as the same as they're using a variable :)  I seem them as different as one says "use this variable as it is now" the other says "use this variable as it is defined when I need it".   In the first case, changing the variable doesn't update the scroll handler assignment as that's already happened - this is your scroll event in the update.  The second case works as it uses the variable as defined at the time of the click.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to change anything within your function as the value of `content` will be read at the point the `click` event happens.

What you have will work absolutely fine, so long as the `content` variable is defined within scope of both locations in your code base.

You should note that `content` itself will be a jQuery object, so you don't need to wrap it again in the click handler; just `content.animate({...` will work fine.

Comment: Thanks for this info. I was looking for an answer like this.

And you gave the decisive tipp. My problem was that the variable already was a jquery object. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you already define the variable as selector so no need to write $(content) you can write below code to execute properly.

```
if(viewportWidth < 768){
 content = $('.content-wrap');
 content.animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 1000);
}else{
 content = $('html, body');
 content.animate({scrollTop: target.offset().top}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: `$($($($("#id")))` is the same as `$('#id')` - it has no impact if you wrap a jquery object in `$()`.  You don't *need* to, but you *can*.